# verify presence of file in parent directory

Tags: python, validation, directory

I'm trying to verify if a file exists in the parent directory. The following doesn't seem to be working and i'm not sure why:

```
import os

if os.path.join(os.pardir + '/foo'):
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

Comment: As a side note, `os.path.join(os.pardir + '/foo')` is just concatenating the strings, and passing the single resulting string to `join`, which does nothing. You want a comma, as in `os.path.join(os.pardir, '/foo')`. (Or, if you wanted the `+`, just don't call `join` at all… but you want the `join`, not the `+`.)

Comment: More importantly, as a general rule, if you think you want to verify if a file exists, 90% of the time you don't. Why do you want to verify it? In particular, if you want to open it, just try it, and you'll get an exception if it's not there.

Comment: Because I have to ask the user to confirm overwriting the file if it exists.

Comment: But you _don't_ have to do that. Doing it that way creates a time-of-check vs. time-of-use race condition, which depending on your use case might be a security hole (between your check and your open, they could add a link to a file that they want overwritten) or a major annoyance (e.g., trying to write to a rolling-over log file) or neither, but you have to think it through to figure out whether it's a problem, not just ignore it because it's easier. Also, it can be very annoying for a user to answer an alert confirming that he wants to overwrite a file only to get another alert for failure.

Comment: See [CWE-367](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/367.html) for a better explanation of the security hole in TOCTOU. (Of course it doesn't explain the annoyances, because that's not what CWE cares about.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `os.path.exists`, the problem with your code is `os.path.join(os.pardir + '/foo')` is always going to be `True` as a boolean value of a non-empty string is True.

```
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.pardir, 'foo')):
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

help on `os.path.exists`:

```
>>> print os.path.exists.__doc__
Test whether a path exists.  Returns False for broken symbolic links
```